# Localhost NodeJS and PHP on same domain

Tags: php, node.js, apache, symfony, localhost

I'm developing a project locally with **NodeJS** on *www.foo.com* and want to call a **PHP** app on *subdomain.foo.com*.

It works but it's interpreted as CROSS-ORIGIN so it sends OPTIONS requests and I can't get the thrown error from PHP in the Network browser development tool.

My hosts

```
127.0.0.1    foo.com
127.0.0.1    subdomain.foo.com
```

Apache

```
// foo.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.com
  DocumentRoot "/path/to/my/nodejs/app"
  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

// Symfony2 project on: subdomain.foo.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName subdomain.foo.com
 DocumentRoot "/path/to/my/php/app"
 <Directory /path/to/my/php/app>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>
 </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/subdomain-foo-error.log"
  CustomLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/subdomain-foo-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cross-site XMLHttpRequests problem, so the solution is not really in PHP land, but in Apache itself.

You can do this by adding the line :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

to the `<Directory>` section of the PHP site config. This will allow cross-site XHR requests from anywhere.

Or you can refine and say :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "foo.com"
```

if you only want requests from your main domain

Comment: I understand, but I don't want to have a cross-site issue, I want to have both apps on the same domain. It works on my server but not locally.  It seems that NodeJS stays on localhost:port and not foo.com!

Comment: They're on the same domain, but not the same _subdomain_. Cross-domain is exactly like cross-site. If this works on your server but not locally, then your server's Apache config is permissive and sets the Header for all virtual hosts, whereas your local configuration does not.